# Why does the return value of open(linux) have to be an int instead of say short?

Tags: linux, int, system-calls, return-type, short

In Linux, I noticed that the open system call returns an `int`. But the total number of available file descriptors are only 20 right(correct me if I am wrong)? So why didn't they make the return value to be `short` which would have been more efficient than returning an int.

Comment: Where does 20 come from?

Comment: I am not sure either, but I remember reading it in some textbook that linux has only 20 file descriptors and if all of them are opened and say I create 21st file descriptor, it would overwrite the first one(0 which is stdin), but I am not sure exactly though.

Comment: @lufork I think you need to find a newer textbook...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While an administrator can set low limits if they want, there is no Linux-wide limit of 20.

Specialized servers can have 100k+ or even 1M+ concurrent TCP connections, each of which require one open FD.

However, there are syscalls that return even more limited ranges, such as `reboot` and `stat`, which always return `0` or `-1`. Why do those return `int` instead of 16bit shorts or even 8bit chars?

There are several reasons for this (here outlined for 32bit x86 Linux):

- To make writing system libraries and compilers easier, x86 32bit Linux has a convention that all syscalls return a value in the 32bit register `eax`. There are no exceptions.

  glibc's `open()` is a thin wrapper on top of the actual syscall. There's no point in glibc trying to additional restrictions on that or any other syscalls.

  In the best case, you save 2 bytes for a few nanoseconds. In the worst case, you paint yourself into a corner that it will take a huge migration effort to get out of.
- A CPU is most comfortable working in its native word length. When you have single (non-array) 16bit or 8bit value on 32bit x86, they're generally not faster.

  Due to this, the compiler is likely to turn them into 32bit values anyways when it thinks this will make the program faster overall, which is often the case (by putting the value in a 32bit register or aligning the address to a 32bit boundary).
- It's easier on the programmer. Since most syscalls return `< 0` to indicate an error, it's better to stick to that than to try to be clever about your return value by returning an `unsigned short`.

Answer (score 1):

The number of available file descriptors is a lot more then twenty. The value can be controlled with the ulimit command. The current default value on my linux box is 1024. You can set the value higher if needed.

So, `open` doesn't return a short because there can be a lot more file descriptors then would fit in a short value.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - It does implicitly - the limit can be a *lot* larger than the OP believes.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath clarified.